# Is there a way to replace string with padding?

Tags: string-manipulation, padding

```
Table[Replace["200" <> ToString[i] <> ".0" -> "200" <> ToString[i]], {i, 0, 9}]
Table[Replace["201" <> ToString[i] <> ".0" -> "201" <> ToString[i]], {i, 0, 9}]
```

Is there a way to put these together more efficiently?

Comment: something like: `StringReplace[{"2000.0", "3000.0", "2005.0"}, 
 "200" ~~ d : DigitCharacter ~~ ".0" :> "200" <> d]`?

Comment: If all of the numbers get rounded: `StringReplace[data, ".0" -> ""]`

Comment: `StringReplace[yourstring,s:RegularExpression["20[01]\\d[.]0"]:>StringTake[s,4]]` will match any string "20" followed by "0" or "1" followed by any digit followed by ".0" and will take the first 4 characters of that. Might have been nice if RegularExpression had been given a shorter name like RE.